# "Barplot not defined" when trying to plot a barplot using Vega package in Julia

Tags: plot, julia, bar-chart, vega

I am trying to plot a barplot using the Vega package in Julia 1.3.1 and simply copied the sample codes from the documentation (https://johnmyleswhite.github.io/Vega.jl/barplot.html), however it returns the error message "barplot is not defined".

```
using Vega

x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
y = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1]

barplot(x = x, y = y)
```

```
UndefVarError: barplot not defined

Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at In[4]:5
```

Similar error messages also occur for other types of plots like areaplot. What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/johnmyleswhite/Vega.jl) it looks like Vega hasn't been updated in quite a while - you might want to use [VegaLite](https://github.com/queryverse/VegaLite.jl) which is actively maintained.